# Matching ADC and encoder data in time

Tags: adc, encoder, load-cell

I'm trying to measure load and elongation in homebrew testing machine. The load is measured by the AD7791 ADC and elongation is measured by linear incremental encoder (quadrature encoder + MCU interrupts). These two parts work fine, but encoder readings update much faster than ADC ones. I can definitely see that load is lagging on graphs, especially on slowest conversion rates of AD7791.

The value of encoder counter is almost instantaneous while ADC conversion takes time. Every time ADC outputs fresh data I send both values to UART, but these are encoder position at the moment of transfer and the load value that took place somewhere between previous and current ADC conversion results.

How can I precisely measure this time lag and what is the common way to eliminate it?

Comment: The best way would be to use a common clock to read both sensors, that way you know the data is recorded simultaneously.  If you use different clocks, it won't be recorded simultaneously, but if the clocks are relatively stable you can probably measure the delay between them and subtract at least some of it off.  How precisely do you need the measurements to align?

Comment: The value of encoder counter is almost instantaneous while ADC conversion takes time. Every time ADC outputs fresh data I send both values to UART, but these are encoder position at the moment of transfer and the load value that took place somewhere between previous and current ADC conversion results.

Comment: @Tolik4 I'd likely start with post-analysis. Are you familiar with the general field of time delay analysis. For example, the use of correlation as one avenue here? I'd like to see plots. (Can you pause changing the load? If so, how long does it take for the elongation and/or load measurements to stop changing?) It's not just the two sensor systems themselves, but you also have the test material in the loop, don't you? Maybe its response to load changes also is not instantaneous?

Comment: @Tolik4 [Here's a sampling of what I'm casting towards](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8925311/pdf/nihms-1781013.pdf). Just to be clearer.

Comment: just to add, even with a perfect system, you will still have some level of time-uncertainty offset between the measurements, the only question is how much. At the moment you have a high offset, but you should be able to reduce that because you have some certainty about how big the offset is (you can check how long the AD7791 takes to do a conversion and then subtract that from the time you get the result) - eventually the offset will be dominated by the uncertainty of the ADC clock / your system clock / various other stuff

Comment: What settings should I use for this analysis? Slowest loading speed possible and fastest ADC sampling rate? Will it help? Or maybe I should stick to the settings that I'm planning to use in real material tests?

Comment: I would measure the delay in the circumstances you want to run the device.  Do it multiple times and look at how much the delay varies, then you can decide if the variation is tolerable or if you need to better synchronize the measurements.

Comment: connect the ADC to the encoder signal to determine the delay between the encoder data and the ADC data

Comment: perhaps an ADC with a sample-and-hold stage at the input would be more suitable